# Redirect all urls to HTTPS except one which starts with "/api"

Tags: laravel, apache, apache2

How can I redirect all requests from http to https except requests to api? Url for api starts with /api.
I used this config but seems not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Could you please tell me where I did it wrong? Project is written in Laravel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: for example, you can start the rules with RewriteRule `^(api) - [L]`

Comment: Can I suggest you don't do this? You shouldn't have this problem, you should be upgrading all requests. Maybe reconsider how you're developing this?

Comment: @ian So desktop dev team developed app which do requests via http. Now customer wants to do redirects from http to https for web version. And I can't just set manual redirect to https because older clients (older desktop app versions) will crash.

Comment: I would say go back to them and ask them to support https rather than you making weird changes. Anyhow, best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this you can create a middleware named `checkHttps` and paste the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class checkHttps {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if(!request()->is('api/*')) {
            if (!$request->secure()) {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And then add your middleware to kernel

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\checkHttps::class,
    ],
];
```

hopefully this will solve your problem.